# Fading edge for vertically-scrollable TextView

Tags: android, textview

I've got a TextView that is vertically-scrollable. How to add fading edge to it?

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="25dp"
/>
```

this code doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try using gradient background?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Yes, I've tried it - it works, but I hope to find why fading edge doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at this anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561701/how-to-fade-edge-of-textview-in-android

Answer (score 1):

try add
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
that really faded the top border.

still trying to figure out with the bottom...

Comment: That worked for me at the bottom. I also increased the thickness with `android:fadingEdgeLength`